# INSERT FROM SELECT UPDATE ON DUPLICATES UPDATE = count(*)

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-update, sql-insert

Updating the count of frequent terms in a dictionary for some corpus. Unable to do in a single query. Instead, I gather count data into a temporary table and then INSERT/UPDATE the dictionary. Wondering what the proper syntax would be to UPDATE countInCorpus in a single command.

Current syntax:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table (name, countInCorpus)
    SELECT name,count(*) AS theCount
    FROM corpus
    GROUP BY name having theCount > 9);

INSERT INTO dict (name, countInCorpus)
    SELECT name, countInCorpus
    FROM temp_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dict.countInCorpus=temp_table.countInCorpus;
```

Failing one-step syntax (resulting in "unknown column 'theCount' in field list") :

```
INSERT INTO dict (name, countInCorpus) 
    SELECT name,count(*) AS theCount
    FROM corpus
    GROUP BY name having theCount > 9
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dict.countInCorpus=theCount;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VALUES()`:

```
INSERT INTO dict (name, countInCorpus) 
    SELECT name,count(*) AS theCount
    FROM corpus
    GROUP BY name havingtheCount > 9
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dict.countInCorpus = VALUES(countInCorpus);
```

Comment: working. thanks. (note that there is a typo -- the threshold value is missing on the fourth line  theCount > 9)